# Unable to set the X-axis for bar graph containing positive and negative values in d3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar graph in d3(react) containing both positive and negative values. By setting the x-axis exactly at origin, I was able to create bars above and below origin when data contains positive and negative values respectively. But the problem comes when my data  has both negative values.
When data contains positive and negative  values:
[positive  and negative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xna2.png)

when data contains both negative values:
[Both negative values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQy1I.png)

function calling the bar chart:

```
const DisplayBarChart = (props) => {
    const data = props.data;
    const yLabel = '';
    const xLabel = '';
    const width = 460;
    const height = 385;
    const translateX = 60;
    const translateY = 20;
    const multicolor = 'true';
    const noZeroes = data.length > 0 ? props.data.filter((d) => d.value !== 0) : [];
    const yMinValue = d3.min(noZeroes, (d) => d.value) - 1;
    const gridlines = 'false';
    const barlabel = 'true';
    const textSymbol = '%';
    const sign = '+';

    return (
        <div className={ defaultTheme.bordered } id="peer">
            <h2 className="pct-h2-line">{props.title}</h2>
            {data.length > 0 &&
                <PCTBarChart
                    data={ data }
                    labelx={ xLabel }
                    labely={ yLabel }
                    width={ width }
                    height={ height }
                    allowMulticolor={ multicolor }
                    translateX={ translateX }
                    translateY={ translateY }
                    multicolors={ ['#FF44CC', '#6f6f6f'] }
                    color={ '#009BDF' }
                    YAxisMinValue={ yMinValue }
                    YAxisMaxValue={ 0.5 }
                    gridlines={ gridlines }
                    textSymbol={ textSymbol }
                    barlabel={ barlabel }
                    sign={ sign }
                />
                }
        </div>
    );
};
```

Code for barchart:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable max-statements */
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

function PCTbarChart(props) {
    const width = props.width * 0.75;
    const height = props.height * 0.65;
    const data = props.data;
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const cache = useRef(props.data);
    const allowMulticolor = props.allowMulticolor;
    const multicolors = props.multicolors;
    const color = props.color;
    const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(multicolors);
    const yMinValue = props.YAxisMinValue;
    const yMaxValue = props.YAxisMaxValue;
    const yAxisTickFormat = props.yAxisTickFormat;
    useEffect(
        () => {
            // defining Axis Scales
            const xScale = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width / 1.1]).padding(0.5);

            const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([yMinValue, d3.max(data, (d) => d.value) + yMaxValue])
                .rangeRound([height, 0]);

            d3.select(ref.current).selectAll('g').remove();
            const group = d3.select(ref.current);
            const groupWithAxis = group.selectAll('g.Axis').data([0]);
            const groupWithData = group.selectAll('g.bar').data(data);

            // initializing X and Y Scales with Values
            xScale.domain(data.map((d) => d.name));

            const groupAxisUpdate = groupWithAxis
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'Axis');

            const groupWithUpdate = groupWithData
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'barGroup');

            const bars = groupWithUpdate
                .append('rect')
                .merge(groupWithData.select('.bar'));

            const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
                .tickSize(0);

            const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
                .tickFormat(yAxisTickFormat);

            // creating the x axis
            groupAxisUpdate
                .append('g')
                .classed('x-axis', true)
                .style('font-size', '0px')
                .attr('transform', `translate(0,${yScale(0)})`)
                .call(xAxis);


            groupAxisUpdate
                .append('g')
                .classed('y-axis', true)
                .style('font-size', '5px')
                .call(yAxis);

            bars
                .attr('class', 'bar')
                .attr('x', (d) => xScale(d.name))
                .transition()
                .duration(950)
                .attr('y', (d) => (d.value > 0 ? yScale(d.value) : yScale(0)))
                .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
                // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
                .attr('height', (d) => (d.value > 0 ? Math.abs(yScale(d.value) - yScale(0)) : Math.abs(yScale(0) - yScale(d.value))))
                .delay((d, i) => i * 550)
                .style('fill', (d) => ((allowMulticolor === 'true') ? colorScale(d.value) : color));

            // labelling the bars
            if (props.barlabel === 'true') {
                groupWithUpdate.append('text')
                    .data(data)
                    .attr('class', 'label')
                    .attr('y', (d) => (d.value > 0 ? yScale(d.value) - 5 : yScale(d.value) + 15))
                    .attr('x', (d) => xScale(d.name) + 15)
                    .text((d) => {
                        if (d.value > 0) {
                            return `${props.sign}${d.value}${props.textSymbol}`;
                        }
                        return `${d.value}${props.textSymbol}`;
                    });
            }
            cache.current = props.data;
        },
        [props.data]
    );

    return (
        <svg width={ props.width } height={ props.height }>
            <g
                ref={ ref }
                transform={ `translate(${props.translateX},${props.translateY})` }
            />
        </svg>
    );
}

export default PCTbarChart;
```

I tried with height instead of YScale(0) but no luck. Any help is much appreciated.